# Origin of the name Duff Kerrigan?

Tags: inspiration, name-significance

Duff Kerrigan is a fictional detective featuring in a series of [21st-century detective stories](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/21704608-duff-kerrigan-pi) by Jim Ingraham.

That doesn't seem like a very common name, and yet it appears in exactly the same form in another place: a piece of graffiti from 1895 on an ancient Greek temple near Athens ([source of image](https://moltmania.com/cape-sounion-saronic-gulf/)):

[image: graffiti picture]

Is there any connection between these two occurrences of the same name? Is there any evidence that Jim Ingraham was inspired by the Sounion graffiti to create his character? Or is it just a big coincidence?

Comment: Kerrigan is a name of Irish origin, though North Shields is in NE England. Maybe he had seen the photo or the original graffiti, and the name stuck in his memory?

Comment: @KateBunting 'Maybe he had seen the photo...memory?' is exactly OPs question, 'is there evidence of that?'

Comment: @Spagirl - I don't see how we can possibly know unless the author is on record somewhere as having said so.

Comment: @KateBunting Sorry if I wasn't clear. I wasn't asking you, but observing that your comment repeats OP's question, which doesn't seem to add or clarify anything to the question.